# JavaScript, image changing program not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm new to coding, so thought that I would give some more simple things a go. I tried to make a code which would change an image every time a button is pressed, but it does not function. For a while I had it functioning so that the square would display but the image would not change when the button is pressed. But I then altered it and it will now not run with internet explorer due to a syntax error. Any help would be seriously appreciated, please bare in mind that it could be completely wrong, as I just used guides off of the internet :) I also probably inserted this code wrong, but I tried ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<img id="shape" src="square.gif">

<button type="button" onclick="changeImage()">Change Image/button>

<script>
var list = [
"red.gif",
"square.gif"

];

var index = 0;

function changeImage() {
index = index + 1;

if (index == list.length) index = 0;

var image = document.getElementById('shape');
image.src=list[index];
}
</script>
```

Comment: What's the syntax error? That would be helpful for figuring out what's going wrong.

Comment: this code is working and changing the src correctly on ie 11 just fix the button tag missing <

Answer (score 4):

I did find two things that will help your code work better:

1. I fixed your closing button tag
2. I iterated your index variable after the if statement and image replacement.  That way your first click didn't use the same image.

This tested fine in IE with no errors.

See my code below.

```js
var list = [
"http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/140.jpg",
"http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/139.jpg"
];
var index = 0;

function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById('shape');
  if (index == list.length) index = 0;
  image.src=list[index];
  index = index + 1;
}
```

```html
<img id="shape" src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/139.jpg" />
<button type="button" onclick="changeImage()">Change Image</button>
```

Comment: Turns out that my answer (submitted at the same time) is basically a duplicate of @haltersweb 's answer.  I am removing mine.  Plus, you know... "kittens!"